# Why does my JavaScript variable return 'null' instead of Html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some JavaScript that is not working:

```
    const player = document.getElementById("player");
    console.log(player);
    
    var positionX = 600;
    var positionY = 200;
    
    document.onkeypress = function move(e) {
      console.log(e.key);
      let keyPressed = e.key;
      if (keyPressed == 'w') {
        positionY--;
        player.style.top = positionY + 'px';
        console.log(player);
      }
    };
```

And in the console, the 'player' variable prints as 'null' when I have tried setting it to the 'player' div in my Html.

Here is the Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movement</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="player"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

An error also shows up:

```
index.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at HTMLDocument.move (index.js:12:12)
move @ index.js:12
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your JavaScript searches for the element before the DOM is rendered, so the `player` variable is instead `null`.

You can add the `script` after the player div:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movement</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="player"></div>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or wait for the DOM to be rendered with

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const player = document.getElementById("player");
    console.log(player);
    
    var positionX = 600;
    var positionY = 200;
    
    document.onkeypress = function move(e) {
      console.log(e.key);
      let keyPressed = e.key;
      if (keyPressed == 'w') {
        positionY--;
        player.style.top = positionY + 'px';
        console.log(player);
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: @AndreasNagelgaard, you can put the script before the closing tag </body>

Comment: @AndreasNagelgaard I have edited my post to show both possibilities. I recommend to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event, because the `script` remains in the head.

Answer (score 0):

You should put you script inside ***window.onload()***

**Example :**

```
window.onload = () => {
    /* put you script here */
}
```

Or call you ***js file*** at bottom of ***HTML***

***Because you script executed before all html element ready !***

Comment: I would not recommend to use `window.onload` because it waits for all pictures and stylesheets to be fully loaded and there is no need to do so while `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {})` only waits for the DOM to be parsed and accessibbe

Comment: Yes, you are right ;)